Keeping state on a react hook
I am still learning react and I currently have an issue where I am trying to create custom hooks and have it make different calls but rentain value of calls already made. Currently, the calls are made but previous values get set back to default which is not what I want.I want to be able to retain  previous data. If this is not possible I would like to get that information or other approach to it.
export const createInitialState = <T, E = Error>(
    initialData: T,
    withPagination = false,
    initialPaginationParams?: Partial<OffsetPaginationParams>
): ApiState<T, E> => ({
    data: initialData,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    ...(withPagination
        ? {
              pagination: {
                  ...DEFAULT_PAGINATION_PARAMS,
                  ...initialPaginationParams,
              },
          }
        : {}),
});

export function apiStateReducer<T, E = Error>(
    state: ApiState<T, E>,
    action: ApiAction<T, E>
): ApiState<T, E> {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "REQUEST":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null,
            };

        case "SUCCESS":
            const newData =
                typeof action.payload === "function"
                    ? (action.payload as (prev: T) => T)(state.data)
                    : action.payload;

            return {
                ...state,
                data: newData,
                loading: false,
                error: null,
            };

        case "FAILURE":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };

        case "SET_PAGINATION_PARAMS":
            if (!state.pagination) {
                return state;
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                pagination: {
                    ...state.pagination,
                    ...action.params,
                },
            };

        case "RESET":
            return createInitialState<T, E>(state.data, !!state.pagination);

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

interface UseApiStateOptions {
    withPagination?: boolean;
    initialPaginationParams?: Partial<PaginationParams>;
}

export function useApiState<T, E = Error>(
    initialData: T | null = null,
    options: UseApiStateOptions = {}
) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
        apiStateReducer<T, E>,
        createInitialState<T, E>(
            initialData,
            options.withPagination,
            options.initialPaginationParams
        )
    );

    const setLoading = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "REQUEST" });
    }, []);

    const setData = useCallback((data: T) => {
        dispatch({ type: "SUCCESS", payload: data });
    }, []);

    const setError = useCallback((error: E) => {
        dispatch({ type: "FAILURE", error });
    }, []);

    const setPaginationParams = useCallback(
        (params: Partial<PaginationParams>) => {
            dispatch({ type: "SET_PAGINATION_PARAMS", params });
        },
        []
    );

    const reset = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "RESET" });
    }, []);

    return {
        state,
        setLoading,
        setData,
        setError,
        setPaginationParams,
        reset,
    };
}

Then in my customHook
interface TicketData {
    tickets: Ticket[];
    total: number;
    selectedTicket: Ticket | null;
    tasks: TicketTask[];
    notes: TicketNote[];
    conversations: TicketComment[];
    activities: UserActivity[];
}

const initialData: TicketData = {
    tickets: [],
    total: 0,
    selectedTicket: null,
    tasks: [],
    notes: [],
    conversations: [],
    activities: [],
};

export function useTickets() {
    const { state, setLoading, setData, setError, setPaginationParams, reset } =
        useApiState<TicketData>(initialData, {
            withPagination: true,
            initialPaginationParams: {
                page: 1,
                pageSize: 20,
            },
        });

        console.log("Current state in useTickets:", state.data);

    const fetchComments = useCallback(
        async (ticketId: string) => {
            console.log("Fetched comments PRE:", state.data);
            try {
                setLoading();
                const result = await ticketService.listComments(ticketId);
                console.log("Fetched comments:", result?.data);

                setData({
                    ...state.data!,
                    conversations: result?.data ?? [],
                });

                return result?.data ?? [];
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching comments:", error);
                setError(error as Error);
                return [];
            }
        },
        [setData, setError, setLoading]
    );

    const selectTicket = useCallback(
        async (id: string) => {
            try {
                setLoading();
                const ticket = await ticketService.getTicket(id);
                console.log("Fetched ticket:", ticket);

                setData({
                    ...state.data!,
                    selectedTicket: ticket ?? null,
                });

                return ticket;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error selecting ticket:", error);
                setError(error as Error);
                throw error;
            }
        },
        [state.data]
    );

    return {
        // State
        ...state.data,
        isLoading: state.loading,
        error: state.error,
        paginationParams: state.pagination,
        total: state.data.total,

        // Operations
        fetchComments,
        selectTicket,
        setPaginationParams,
        reset,
    };
}

Now in my Component
export const TicketDetailsPage = () => {
    const { ticketId } = useParams();

    const isInitialLoadRef = useRef(true);

    const {
        selectedTicket,
        conversations = [],
        activities = [],
        tasks = [],
        notes = [],
        isLoading,
        selectTicket,
        fetchComments,
    } = useTickets();

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {
            if (!ticketId) return;

            try {
                console.log("Loading data for ticket:", ticketId);

                // Load ticket first
                await selectTicket(ticketId);

                // Load all related data in parallel
                await Promise.all([
                    fetchComments(ticketId),
                ]);

                console.log("All data loaded");
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error loading ticket data:", error);
            }
        };

        if (isInitialLoadRef.current && ticketId) {
            loadData();
            isInitialLoadRef.current = false;
        }
    }, [
        ticketId,
        selectTicket,
        fetchComments,
    ]);
    ...

So now when selectTicket gets called, I see the data but once fetchComments gets called, it automatically sets selectedTicket which should not be.
If you need more information kindly let me know. I appriciate every help possible.

Issue
The fetchComments callback has a Javascript Closure issue, in that it closes over the un-updated state value which is passed into the setData success action and unconditionally overwrites whatever the current state is.
Trivially you could add all the missing hook dependencies to the useCallback hook call.
const fetchComments = useCallback(
  async (ticketId: string) => {
    console.log("Fetched comments PRE:", state.data);
    try {
      setLoading();
      const result = await ticketService.listComments(ticketId);
      console.log("Fetched comments:", result?.data);

      setData({
        ...state.data!,
        conversations: result?.data ?? [],
      });

      return result?.data ?? [];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching comments:", error);
      setError(error as Error);
      return [];
    }
  },
  [setData, setError, setLoading, state] // <-- add state as a dependency
);

But this only really pushes the Closure issue down stream. For example, now the useEffect hook call in TicketDetailsPage will get a new "copy" of the fetchComments, but the currently in-flight loadData fetching the data and dispatching actions to the useReducer hook won't ever see the updated copy.
Solution Suggestion
Don't try to pass any current state along with any new values you are wanting to add to the state. Handle merging all new state into the current state in the reducer cases. This avoids the stale closure issue of trying to manage this outside the reducers.
case "SUCCESS":
  const newData =
    typeof action.payload === "function"
      ? (action.payload as (prev: T) => T)(state.data)
      : action.payload;

    return {
      ...state,
      data: {
        ...state.data, // <-- shallow copy current data here!
        ...newData,    // <-- shallow merge new data here
      },
      loading: false,
      error: null,
    };

Now selectTicket and fetchComments need only pass the new data in the action, removing state as a useCallback hook dependency.
const selectTicket = useCallback(
  async (id: string) => {
    try {
      setLoading();
      const ticket = await ticketService.getTicket(id);
      console.log("Fetched ticket:", ticket);

      setData({
        selectedTicket: ticket ?? null,
      });

      return ticket;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error selecting ticket:", error);
      setError(error as Error);
      throw error;
    }
  },
  [setData, setError, setLoading]
);

const fetchComments = useCallback(
  async (ticketId: string) => {
    console.log("Fetched comments PRE:", state.data);
    try {
      setLoading();
      const result = await ticketService.listComments(ticketId);
      console.log("Fetched comments:", result?.data);

      setData({
        conversations: result?.data ?? [],
      });

      return result?.data ?? [];
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching comments:", error);
      setError(error as Error);
      return [];
    }
  },
  [setData, setError, setLoading]
);

Since it looks like you also typed your action payload to accept a callback function that is passed the current state.data value I suspect you could also implement a functional state update as well. Something like the following:
setData(data => ({
  ...data,
  selectedTicket: ticket ?? null,
}));

setData(data => ({
  ...state.data,
  conversations: result?.data ?? [],
}));

Between the two though the first is preferable since it doesn't rely on downstream consumers of the state and handlers to know and maintain any part of your state invariant, e.g. it's shape & properties. Complete and sole responsibility for updating the state rests fully on the case reducers.

Thank you for your response.
using
setData({                     conversations: result?.data ?? [],                 });
or
setData({         selectedTicket: ticket ?? null,       });
gives the error
Argument of type '{ conversations: TicketComment[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TicketData'.
Type '{ conversations: TicketComment[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TicketData': tickets, total, selectedTicket, tasks, and 2 more.
and spreading it out as the second option you gave also returned errors.

Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.
Argument of type '(data: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TicketData'.ts(2345)

I just realized that the passage of initialData seems to be the probelm. When I removed it and declared my useApiState without it, the values were persisted.

@King It's been a long time since I used the useReducer hook. I'll see if I what I can reproduce in a running CodeSandbox when I have availability.

Thanks. Do you use anything asisdes the useReducer hook? Like an alternative?

@King Interesting. I also just realized that I don't have enough details to reproduce your code on my end, namely missing the extra types/interfaces. Think you can create a running CodeSandbox demo of your code?

@King "Do you use anything asisdes the useReducer hook? Like an alternative?" - I use Redux for global app states.
